# When i use delay should i switch to Default or IO thread from main thread

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

Sometimes my fragment scope needs to wait before executes some view stuffs. In these cases i am adding *delay(ms)* function into my scope. But my scope initialized with the **Dispathers.Main** . I know unlike **Thread.sleep(ms)**, **delay(ms)** is not blocking current thread. Should i consider which thread executes **delay** function ?

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
        scope.launch {
            //do i really need to switch IO
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                delay(4000)
            }
            someUIStuff()
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's a simple rule: you never need `withContext()` to call a `suspend fun`.

Comment: Thank you @MarkoTopolnik it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

**No** need to switch, `delay` is a `suspend` function, it will suspend the current `Coroutinescope` not the executing `Thread`. As per documentation of `delay` function, check the first point

```
/**
 * Delays coroutine for a given time without blocking a thread and resumes it after a specified time.
 * This suspending function is cancellable.
 * If the [Job] of the current coroutine is cancelled or completed while this suspending function is waiting, this function
 * immediately resumes with [CancellationException].
 *
 * Note that delay can be used in [select] invocation with [onTimeout][SelectBuilder.onTimeout] clause.
 *
 * Implementation note: how exactly time is tracked is an implementation detail of [CoroutineDispatcher] in the context.
 * @param timeMillis time in milliseconds.
 */
public suspend fun delay(timeMillis: Long) {
    if (timeMillis <= 0) return // don't delay
    return suspendCancellableCoroutine sc@ { cont: CancellableContinuation<Unit> ->
        cont.context.delay.scheduleResumeAfterDelay(timeMillis, cont)
    }
}
```